# Can you access physical drive data from a UWP app?

Tags: file-io, uwp

I need to overwrite the filesystem of a USB stick with raw data. While a `FolderPicker` can access e.g. `D:\`, it can't be used to access e.g. `\.\PhysicalDrive1`. Is there a way to access physical drive data from a UWP or is it not possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can access USB stick like this:

```
StorageFolder externalDevices = KnownFolders.RemovableDevices;
StorageFolder usbStick = (await externalDevices.GetFoldersAsync()).FirstOrDefault();
var usbStickFolder = await usbStick.CreateFolderAsync("test", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
var file = await usbStickFolder.CreateFileAsync("test.txt", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

But this code would not work before you not set File Type Associations in app manifest. Otherwise it will throw Access Denied exception.

[image]

Comment: I know this, but I need to overwrite the stick with _raw filesystem data_. A file extension isn't applicable here, that's the issue.

Comment: Then I do not understand the question. What means `\.\PhysicalDrive1` and `raw filesystem data`? It's *unix filesystem? Or you need to format usb stick or somthing like this?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to make a startup disk creator. In Win32, `\.\PhysicalDrive<number> ` instead of `<letter>:\ ` is how you access the raw partitioning/filesystem data itself. Looks like UWP just doesn't allow for any sort of low-level system stuff...

Comment: I think the way to solve this lies in the [Win32 API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/win32-and-com/win32-and-com-for-uwp-apps) and `[DllImport("somedll.dll")]` attribute. But I think it will be very dirty, even if it works.